# aurelia cli and mysqljs dependencies

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, command-line-interface, aurelia

I have some problems with install mysqljs to my project (Aurelia CLI Typescript).
I installed it by node.js by command "npm install mysql", next I added in aurelia.json to my bundles dependencies (I don't think so that it is correct)

```
{
        "name": "mysql",
        "path": "../node_modules/mysql",
        "main": "index"
      }
```

and my .ts file looks like here:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import * as mysql from 'mysql';

export class ForOrganizers {
  constructor() {


    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : 'password',
      database : 'test'
    });

  }

}
```

and in gulp i have this errors:

```
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/crypto.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/events.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/net.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/tls.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/url.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/bignumber.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/packets.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/timers.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/stream.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/util.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/sqlstring.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/fs.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/readable-stream.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/node_modules/mysql/.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/crypto.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/events.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/net.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/tls.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/url.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/bignumber.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/packets.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/timers.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/stream.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/util.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/sqlstring.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/fs.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/src/readable-stream.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
File not found or not accessible: C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/node_modules/mysql/.js. Requested by C:/xampp/htdocs/bike-ride/dist/bike-ride/for-organizers.js
```

Project can't find libraries, but why?
Can somebody help me please?
Thanks

Comment: can help me anyone?

Comment: The `mysql` package is a NodeJS package. You wouldn't run this on your client code (your Aurelia app).

Comment: You would use this package in your server app and then build an API for your Aurelia app to talk to it (for example, a REST API).

Comment: @AshleyGrant can U give me tutorial to build an API?